# Stylistically, how best to connect the following two short clauses?

Tags: constructions

> Le café est mauvais pour le sommeil, dont la qualité s'en ressent.
>
> Le café est mauvais pour le sommeil ; sa qualité s'en ressent.
>
> Le café est mauvais pour le sommeil, il en dégrade la qualité.
>
> Le café est mauvais pour le sommeil dont il dégrade la qualité.

I want to test the waters a bit here to see how the three different phrasings "sa qualité", "dont ... la qualité", and "en ... la qualité" sound in this sentence.

Comment: Aucune des phrases ne me plaît mais je crains fort que ce soit une question d'opinion et qu'on pourra avoir  20 phrases différentes ou plus ! La mienne :  *Boire du café altère la qualité du sommeil.*

Comment: @Laure Ja, I know, they are kind of stiff. I wouldn't use any of them in casual conversation. But... for the sake of discussing sentence constructions, please! :) Do all four versions sound correct, at least?

Comment: The last one sounds the least weird to my ears. I can't picture myself saying the first 2. But  I'd stick to *altérer la qualité du sommeil* in real speech.

Comment: Le 3 est correct, voire soutenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dont" is a relative pronoun which is equivalent to **"de" + antecedent** in the relative:

> Il connaît l'homme *dont* nous avons parlé.
>
> Nous avons parlé de l'homme qu'il connaît.

> Le **café** est mauvais pour le sommeil *dont* **il** dégrade la qualité.
>
> Le café (est mauvais car il) dégrade la qualité du sommeil.

Some alternative forms:

> Le café est mauvais pour le **sommeil**, il dégrade **sa** qualité.
>
> Le café est mauvais pour le **sommeil** car il **l**'empêche.

To disambiguate sentences where two subject compete, "de ce dernier" (*of the latter*) can be used:

> Le café est mauvais pour le sommeil parce qu'il réduit la qualité de ce dernier.
>
> Le café est mauvais pour le sommeil, ayant un impact négatif sur la qualité de ce dernier.